# MATLAB (Month Segmentation)

Tags: matlab

I have a set of data from January to December. I need to write a program that will segment a specific 3 months to differentiate and represent data in terms of 4 seasons. can anyone help? I have did for separating weekday and weekend as below:

```
[load,txt]=xlsread('2011data.xlsx');
date=txt(2:end,1);
dateNumber=datenum(date);
k=1;
j=1;
cnt=size(dateNumber,1);

for i=1:cnt

    DayNum=weekday(dateNumber(i));
    if DayNum == 1 || DayNum == 7 || DayNum == 6
        weekendDate(j,1)= dateNumber(i, 1);
        weekendLoad(j,1)= load(i,1);
        j = j+1;

    else
        weekdayDate(k,1)= dateNumber(i,1);
        weekdayLoad(k,1)= load(i,1);
        k = k+1;

    end
end
```

It should be something similar but I just couldn't get it. thanks

Comment: Look at the month? Have a lookuptable for the seasons and check which one the current month lies in?

Comment: I mean to separate the data into few files in my workspace, for autumn ( it is which month to which), for winter(it is which month to which). thgs like that. if u run my code above u will understand what i want

Comment: hint: use `datevec` to split the datenumber up and retrieve the month.